# Phalcon MongoDb save

Tags: mongodb, phalcon

I have problem with save method of collections in Phalcon.It doesn't work and doesn't give me any errors or something.I want to create a Micro App with mongoDb:

Phalcon version: 1.3.4
php : 5.5.9

Here are the registered services:

```html
<?php

use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault,
    Phalcon\Assets\Manager as AssetsManager,
    Phalcon\Mvc\Collection\Manager as CollectionManager,
    Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple as View,
    Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt,
    Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlResolver,
    Phalcon\Flash\Session as Flash,
    Phalcon\Flash\Direct as FlashDirect,
    Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files as Session;

$di = new FactoryDefault();

$di['url'] = function () {
    $url = new UrlResolver();
    $url->setBaseUri('/dasshy/');
    return $url;
};

/**
 * Flash service with custom CSS classes
 */
$di['flash'] = function () {
    return new Flash(array(
        'error' => 'alert alert-error',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
    ));
};

/**
 * Flash service with custom CSS classes
 */
$di['flashDirect'] = function () {
    return new FlashDirect(array(
        'error' => 'alert alert-error',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
    ));
};

$di['session'] = function () {
    $session = new Session(array(
        'uniqueId' => 'dasshy-'
    ));
    $session->start();
    return $session;
};

$di['mongo'] = function () {
    $mongo = new MongoClient();
    return $mongo->selectDb("stats");
};

$di->set('collectionManager', function () {
    return new Phalcon\Mvc\Collection\Manager();
});
```

I want to use the ODM, so here is the model Collection:

```js
<?php

namespace Dasshy\Models;

class Messages extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection
{
    public $content;

    public $senderId;

    public $receiverId;

    public $date;

}
```

And here how i use it at handlers.php:

```html
<?php

use Dasshy\Models\Messages;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection;


$app->map('/send/{receiverId}/{senderId}/{content}', function ($receiverId, $senderId, $content) use ($app) {


    $messageModel = new Messages();

    $messageModel->receiverId = $receiverId;
    $messageModel->senderId = $senderId;
    $messageModel->content = $content;
    $messageModel->date = date('Y-m-d H-i-s', time());
    $messageModel->save();

    if ($messageModel->save() == false) {
        echo "Umh, We can't store robots right now: \n";
        foreach ($messageModel->getMessages() as $message) {
            echo $message, "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Great, a new robot was saved successfully!";
    }
});

$app->map('/messages', function () use ($app) {

    var_dump(Messages::find());
    exit;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup the mongo connection on the service...

```
        $config = $di->getShared('config')->mongo;
        $connect_data = $config->username . ':' . $config->password . '@' . $config->host . ':' . $config->port . '/' . $config->dbname;
        $mongo = new \MongoClient("mongodb://" . $connect_data);
        return $mongo->selectDB($config->dbname);
```

...since you are not connecting to any mongo server